# Посоветуйте толковые книги по Android

Tags: android, книги

Я знаю, что таких вопросом множество.
Я просмотрел ряд книг которые горячо советовались в подобных темах, но, например, ни в одной не нашел информации про LoaderManager.

Посоветуйте если не самую лучшую книгу по Android, то несколько книг, которые в совокупности в подробности опишут тонкости написания приложения на Android и будут не просто давать какую-то информацию, а описывать то что написано как можно подробнее.

В первую очередь на русском.

Answer (score 7):

Андроид это не тот предмет который следует учить по книгам, он слишком быстро развивается. Примеры которые предлагались в книгах 2010-2012 года на английском уже сейчас выглядят древними как экскременты мамонта. А русские переводы запаздывают обычно на 3-4 года.  Про качество переводов я вообще молчу - от всяких "активностей" и "намереней" тошнить начинает уже на первой странице.
`startandroid.ru` - единственный вменяемый ресурс на русском, и то добрая половина уроков уже устарела, благо автор находит время их актулизировать, ну или хотя бы ставит пометки что "это устрело, смотрите урок №xxx"

Из источников могу порекомендовать видео с Google IO от разработчиков Андроид и английский стекоферфлоу по конкретным проблемам, и то обращать внимание на дату ответа, и записи в блогах вменяемых людей с примерами за последний год.

Answer (score 5):

Начать стоит с того , что Android - это фреймворк , то есть некоторый набор классов для взаимодействия с системой , программы же для ОС Android пишут , как правило , на Java и первым делом нужно проникнуться знанием именно в этой области программирования .

Если вы не хотите прослыть среди потенциальных пользователей  неким мажором и не будете разрабатывать исключительно под Android 4.4+ , то читать нужно по версии Java 1.6 (она же просто Java 6 ) и здесь все те экскременты мамонта (а Java 6  уже почти десять лет стукнуло ) , что были выпущены на русском языке, вполне уместны и актуальны .

Обычно в этом месте принято советовать читать Брюса Эккеля " Философия Java" . Как раз по такому случаю ,совсем недавно , вышло новое , четвертое ,издание его творения на русском языке , расширенное и исправленное . Почему нужно читать книги по Java , а не сразу по Android ? В книгах по Android делается упор непосредственно на особенностях фреймворка и его использования для реализации поставленной задачи . По ,собственно, программированию и языку там , как правило , ничего толкового нет , а программу , как ни крути , придется писать все же на Java и недурно знать - как это делается .

Теперь о качестве экскрементной литературы в области Android . Да , версия 2.3- уже безнадежно устарела и читать по ней несколько запоздало и лишне , НО! Android 4 ICS до сих пор поддерживается большинством разработчиков , соответственно и книги по этой версии вполне актуальны.А выпущено на русском их было аж несколько штук .

Здесь нужно сразу же сказать , что лучше книги Брайна Харди и Билла Филипса " Программирование под Android " - 2014г. тут что то трудно сыскать .
В книге , на конкретных примерах создания полноценных приложений , раскрываются все тонкости разработки приложений под Android , с подробными объяснениями и комментариями - что конкретно происходит , почему и почему не по другому . Есть там целая глава и по работе с Loaders и достаточно внимания уделено работе с фрагментами .

Затем нельзя обойти вниманием творение Рето Майера , видного инженера гугл по направлению Android - " Android 4. Программирование приложений для планшетных компьютеров и смартфонов" - 2013 .
 Дальше уже можно читать , что попадется и выбирать из этого частички того , что недостаточно освещено в первых двух .

Что касается различных сайтов по программированию , вроде startandroid.ru или уроков Климова и почему нужно все же читать книги ..

Да , эти сайты хороши и содержат много полезного , но как СПРАВОЧНИКИ по реализации типовых задач под Android / Все они содержат пример и некий упрощенный разбор одной конкретной локальной задачи и очень мало , либо вообще не обращают внимания , на такие основополагающие вещи , как архитектура приложения , взаимодействие компонентов разных частей приложения , паттерны проектирования и прочее , что ДЕЛАЕТ приложение приложением , а не сборником разных кусочков копипаста , надерганных с интернет-ресурсов . 
Книги , как правило , более глубоко рассматривают особенности разработки под платформу и дают целостный взгляд на предмет .

Comment: Ну как пример хочется сказать что в веб-программировании почему-то все используют библиотеку JQUERY и изучают ее функции и как с ними работать и бла бла бла... но никто не изучает язык на котором она написана и никто не пишет свою собственую JQUERY т.к. она создавалась годами, профессионалами с опытом огромным, и просто прочитав книгу такое не спрограммируешь. Нужны годы, а решение - как правило сейчас. Поэтому изучают что нужно сейчас, а потом будет время изучат и основы. Может и Androida это касается ?! и к чему велосипеды.. главное понимать что ты используешь :)

Comment: Если бы вы смогли доходчиво объяснить , как писать собственную программу (не какой то копипаст чужих решений ) , не зная языка на котором эту программу пишешь , то я бы с вами и согласился .. Речь вроде идет о том , чтобы научиться писать собственный код , а не "как мне использовать библиотеки"

Comment: Ну изучение начальное не зная языка в частности для Android можно начать и просто копипастом и чтением статей "быстрого обучения". Посмотрел статью, сделал - работает. Поставил задачу что-то изменить - попробовал оказалось недостаточно знаний как писать функции и т.д... - тогда уже смотришь книгу. И т.д... Со временем понадобится учить классы, учить принципы ООП и все соответствующее. А не сидеть годами читать книги по Java 6 и потом только браться за Anroid у которого своих особенностей полно, помимо синтаксиса Java.

Comment: ну я не против , копипастите , читайте "быстрые обучения" , делайте что хотите и как вам больше нравиться - полноценную собственную программу без уверенной систематизированной базы вы не напишите , а из статей в интернетах , уроков startandroid и бездумного копипаста вы ее не получите

Comment: Для меня автор написал желание понять именно Android, т.е что-то типа Android Studio и т.д... Сам сижу читаю про Android, но мне не требуется изучать сначала Java. Я вхожу в это дело постепенно по мере возникновения задач и потребностей. Осознаю синтаксис на примерах, и параллельно изучаю студию позволяющую делать приложения для андроида. По мере усложнения задач, глужбе изучу язык на котором они пишутся. Для меня - это наиболее быстрый способ изучения.

Comment: Согласен с автором. В своем ответе я несколько утрировал, но действительно подразумевается что у человека есть базовые знания Java когда он приступает к Андроид, но также допускаю что саму Java можно учить используя Андроид для визуализации результатов. И уж ни к коей мере я не утверждаю что книги по Java устарели. Но вот с книгам по Андроид беда: да, Андроид 4.0+ сечас актуален, но слишком много практических вещей из этих книг уже deprecated, и изучать заведомо устаревшие вещи несколько глупо, а если примеры из книги вообще не компилирутся, то это вообще ставит в тупик новичков.

Answer (score 4):

[startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/)

это не книга, но автор обращает внимание на тонкости.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошая книга, рекомендую.
Постоянно обновляется.
https://commonsware.com/Android/

Comment: Хорошая книга, но в ней я вижу пару минусов: 3124 страницы и цена $45 за годовую подписку.